# How to enable the Google Compute Engine API using python APIs

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a project, launch a VM and start a service on Google Compute Engine. I could create a new project however right now I need to manually enable the Compute Engine API by visiting the following page: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute-component.googleapis.com/overview?project=

Is there any way to enable the APIs programatically?

Comment: I am trying to fully automate the project launch which I think doesn't fit with the idea of the project. One has to enable atleast few things (billing and api enabling) manually. Subsequent steps can be executed through APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute" to the scopes of the serviceAccount you are using. I do not know how that is done in the Python API but if you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/ and manually add an instance there is an option "Set access for each API" under "Indentity and API access" and "Access scopes". Then select the compute engine API and click the the link at the bottom at the page "Equivalent Rest" to see what the REST request would be to do the same using REST.

You should then probably quite easily be able to translate the same to the Python API.

The documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances).

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically enable API (in Google Terms - add Service to Project) with web requests in next way:

1) Use web request for OAuth2 + callback URL. Scope required:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management

2) In callback URL - get Auth token,  then add to web request header "Authorization", "Bearer " + token and call request as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/serviceusage/v1/serviceusage.services.enable).
URL will look like next:

https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/12345/services/compute-component.googleapis.com:enable

where 12345 - your Project Number (not ProjectId as docs says, but it seems ProjectId works too)

Full list of API you can get [here](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis). "discoveryRestUrl" can contain ID of API as domain. Also see [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/)